What is the default behavior for dealing with interrupts while handling a software exception in embedded C++?
I'm working with nlohmann json on an embedded system and since nlohmann throws exceptions for errors that occur when parsing or accessing the json I wanted to know whether or not the handling of these exceptions might block hardware interrupts from being dealt with until the software exception is handled. I'm not as concerned with the memory usage of interrupts as I am with the potential performance issues if exception handling is blocking interrupts.
Nothing from the nlohmann json documentation or code seems to suggest that it is disabling interrupts but I wasn't sure what the default behavior is in this regard and I couldn't find anything online that talks about the topic. So far nothing says that interrupts are disabled and my intuition would say that unless explicitly disabled by the software then exception handling should not be blocking hardware interrupts but I've also seen nothing that explicitly says interrupts are not disabled by software exceptions by default. Any information would be appreciated!

The C++ spec doesn't deal with hardware interrupts.

Yeah I guess I probably should have left C++ out of the title for clarity, do you know where I might be able to look for an answer though? Wasn't sure if hardware documentation would have anything related to this

You should be able to build the library with JSON_NOEXCEPTION so it won't throw. (which is probably preferable on embedded anyway) However, while a bit expensive, exception handling is stack based so it affects interrupt handling like any other code. So yes you can have re-entrancy and all the other things with normal interrupt handling that might mess things up (like the stack)

nlohmann's docs obviously wouldn't talk about interrupts and such - it is a standard c++ code, as far as it is concerned it operates in some nebulous environment which has no concept of interrupts. Question in your topic header is the relevant one. It is dependant on a particular c++ compiler implementation, but I don't know of any that would mess with interrupt handling. Doubt any c++ exception would block interrupt handling (unless that exception is itself thrown while processing interrupt); the opposite is more likely - interrupt handling would preempt exception handling.

The standard practice is to avoid exceptions entirely whenever using embedded systems or other high integrity applications. If you are dealing with a lib using exceptions, then it was probably not written with high system integrity in mind and so it isn't suitable for the purpose. The general best practice is to avoid exceptions like the plague. This is actually one of the main arguments why C is preferred over C++ in embedded systems.

From a C++ perspective, an "exception" is entirely a userspace-software-construct implemented by the compiler; it's kind of adding an invisible control flow with "if (error) ... else ..." constructs (although actual exception implementations tend to be implemented in a way that does not impact runtime if no exception is thrown, since that's the normal case).
On the other hand, C++ does absolutely nothing with hardware interrupts, or even unix-signals. The hardware-interrupt will just interrupt whatever the program is currently doing, whether it's working on an exception or not. And when the interrupt-function returns, the actual program will just continue whatever it was doing, whether that was processing an exception or not.
Likewise, C++ cannot block hardware interrupts. Regardless of separations between kernel- and userspace, which might not apply in your embedded case(?), C++ does not support or deal with hardware interrupts in any way -- that's beyond the realm of a high-level language.
You might be able to call OS-functions, or special libraries supplied for your system, to actually make the system block hardware interrupts -- but the compiler isn't going to do that for you.
Of course, there's always the possibility that the compiler might be specifically written for your embedded platform and do whatever is needed to block hardware interrupts for some reason -- but that would feel like a very odd choice, since I don't see a reason to do that outside of benchmarking benefits

"or even unix-signals": Behavior of signals is well-defined by the standard. It is reasonable to assume that the semantics of interrupts will be similar to what is specified for signals.

@user17732522 behavior of unix-signals is defined by POSIX; Is an OS dependent issue, which is not in the scope of C++ as a language. Any guarantees on OS related issues must be provided by your platform; ISO C++ doesn't get involved with those matters.

@Red.Wave ISO C++ does specify behavior of signals. See https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.exec, https://eel.is/c++draft/csignal.syn and https://eel.is/c++draft/support.signal, as well as the normative references to ISO C, which also specifies the behavior. POSIX just extents the specification and puts extra requirements on the implementation.

@user17732522 POSIX is not an extension of ISO C++; so the behavior of unix signals is not defined in the context of C++. The gist of provided links is that C++ makes no effort to synchronize with OS signals, except for the calls to std::signal that installs handlers for current process, and within the handler functions written in C++. That leaves a lot of room for OS to deal with signals, which is reasonable and outside the scope of C++ language.

Since this is tagged embedded, then POSIX, Unix, signal handling and hosted system behavior isn't applicable. Unless your definition of an embedded system is something like a phone or laptop running Android...
